# SSL certificate for MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, security, ssl, certificate

I'm trying to implement SSL certificate on a SQL Server and I already tried two methods. I tried with lets encrypt service and self certificate generated on Powershell.

In the first scenario I can see the cert into SQL Server Configuration Manager but then I got an error while restarting the service. I've got the error `2146885628`. First I generated the certificate and followed this [tutorial](http://sqlsunday.com/2017/11/22/encrypting-tds-with-letsencrypt)

On the second scenario the cert is not shown on SQL Server Configuration Manager.

My questions are: Am I making something wrong and what is the best Powershell code to generate a certificate compatible with SQL Server 2016 ?

Comment: For the first scenario, you need to ensure that the SQL Server service account has read permission on the certificate.  https://nickstips.wordpress.com/2010/09/08/sql-ssl-and-sql-server-2008-service-doesnt-start-error-code-2146885628/.  For the second scenario, my first guess would be that the certificate was not imported the local computer's Personal store.  Run certlm.msc (this opens the cert stores for the local computer) and make sure you can see it there.  If you open the cert store by running MMC and adding the snap-in, it's easy to mess up by not selecting "Computer account".

Comment: Also, if you're just wanting to encrypt connections, it isn't necessary to install a cert.  You can use the self-generated cert if you're OK with configuring clients to trust whatever cert the server is using.

Comment: I gave the permissions to the certificate. I noticed on my cert details that I don't have the thumbprint algorithm is not present. i need to secure the data with a cert. we are talking about sensitive data!

Comment: I changed the logon system on Log on to local system and the service starts but I can't connect from another computers. Am I on the good way? Merry christmas